# Object reference while creating a page in Kentico CMS version 7

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, kentico

I have installed latest version of kenticoCMS (v.7) and created a new corporate site. Now I want to create a new page on root website but when I clicking on New page item this is generating error. I have tried the same with another web site but still the error is same for all.

Thanks in advance!

```
Server Error in '/KenticoCMS' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:


Line 209:        get
Line 210:        {
Line 211:            return mStep ?? (mStep = DocumentManager.Step);
Line 212:        }
Line 213:    }


Source File: f:\Asp.net\KenticoCMS\CMSModules\Content\Controls\EditMenu.ascx.cs    Line: 211

Stack Trace:


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   CMS.DocumentEngine.WorkflowManager.GetNodeWorkflowScopeInternal(TreeNode node) +342
   CMS.DocumentEngine.WorkflowManager.GetNodeWorkflowInternal(TreeNode node) +135
   CMS.DocumentEngine.WorkflowManager.GetPublishedWorkflowStepInternal(TreeNode node) +11
   CMS.DocumentEngine.WorkflowManager.GetStepInfoInternal(TreeNode node) +65
   CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode.get_WorkflowStep() +90
   CMS.FormControls.CMSDocumentManager.get_Step() +36
   CMSModules_Content_Controls_EditMenu.get_Step() in f:\Asp.net\KenticoCMS\CMSModules\Content\Controls\EditMenu.ascx.cs:211
   CMSModules_Content_Controls_EditMenu.ReloadMenu() in f:\Asp.net\KenticoCMS\CMSModules\Content\Controls\EditMenu.ascx.cs:448
   CMSModules_Content_Controls_EditMenu.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) in f:\Asp.net\KenticoCMS\CMSModules\Content\Controls\EditMenu.ascx.cs:336
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +103
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.547
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would it be possible to copy and paste the whole error message with the stack trace?
Also, it seems that there is some corrupted file - I do not know which since the screen shot does not show the path of the file that the exception was thrown from.

So, to refresh the files I would recommend e.g. applying the latest [hotfix](http://devnet.kentico.com/Bugtracker/Hotfixes.aspx)